# How to overwrite and edit the hover template of a plotly() 3D object in R

Tags: r, 3d, hover, plotly, scatter-plot

I am creating a 3D scatterplot with `plotly()` and want to formate the hovertemplate. My data has not always the same column names, but at the moment this is how my data looks like and how I construct my plot (column names can differ, therefore I save them in a vector and rename my data table):

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                 spotDE = rnorm(365, 25, 1), windDE = rnorm(365, 10000, 2), 
                 resLoadDE = rnorm(365, 50000, 2), check.names = FALSE)

## Extract the column names of the two selected variables: ##
product1 <- colnames(dt[, 2])
product2 <- colnames(dt[, 3])
product3 <- colnames(dt[, 4])

## Rename the data table: ##
colnames(dt) <- c("date", "prod1", "prod2", "prod3")


## 3D Plot Construction: ##
plot3D <- plot_ly(data = dt, x = ~prod1, y = ~prod2, z =  ~prod3, type = "scatter3d", 
                  mode = "markers", 
                  marker = list(size = 5, 
                                colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("#A1D99B", "#005A32")),
                                showscale = FALSE)
          ) %>%
          layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = product1),
                              yaxis = list(title = product2),
                              zaxis = list(title = product3)), 
                 title = paste('<span style="font-size: 16px;"><b>', product1, "vs.", 
                               product2, "vs.", product3, '</span>'), 
                 margin = list(t = 100))
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: HoverTemplate]

**Now I need your help:** How can I write the respective product in the `hovertemplate` instead of `x`, `y` and `z` (in this case: `spotDE`, `windDE` and `resLoadDE`) ??

I have already tried some different things, but nothing of them works:

**1:** Here only this was added after `x`, `y` and `z`. But I want it instead.

```
text = ~paste(product1, ": ", prod1)
```

**2:** Here only this was added after `x`, `y` and `z`. But I want it instead.

```
hovertemplate = paste("product1:  %{x}<br>",
                      "%{product2}:  %{y}<br>",
                      "%{product3}:  %{z}<extra></extra>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you had was very close. I just added `hoverinfo = 'text'` and then `text` to `plot_ly` referencing `product1`, `product2` and `product3`. You can use `sprintf`, `format`, `round` or other to control more details on numeric output, including decimal places.

```
plot_ly(data = dt, x = ~prod1, y = ~prod2, z =  ~prod3, type = "scatter3d", 
                  mode = "markers", 
                  marker = list(size = 5, 
                                colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("#A1D99B", "#005A32")),
                                showscale = FALSE),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste0(product1, ": ", prod1, "<br>", product2, ": ", prod2, "<br>", product3, ": ", prod3)
) %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = product1),
                      yaxis = list(title = product2),
                      zaxis = list(title = product3)), 
         title = paste('<span style="font-size: 16px;"><b>', product1, "vs.", 
                       product2, "vs.", product3, '</span>'), 
         margin = list(t = 100))
```

**Plot**

[image: plotly with custom hover labels]